# Изучаю OpenGL 3+, почему не рисуется квадрат?

Tags: c++, opengl, шейдеры

Решил попробовать нарисовать квадрат без шейдеров... но в окне не чего нет. Что я сделал не так?

```
float quads1[]{
    -0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
    0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
    0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
    -0.5, -0.5, 0.0
};

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        glfwPollEvents();

        
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, quads1);
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 4);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вроде, в Core Profile нельзя обойтись без шейдеров вообще.

Comment: Не надо писать в заголовке "изучаю OpenGL", вам же уже правили его. Почитайте [ask]

Answer (score 4):

Вы же сами попросили у GLFW "core profile", в котором нет никаких `glEnableClientState` и `glVertexPointer`, а есть только шейдеры.

Или включите "compatibility profile" (`GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE` вместо `GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE`), или рисуйте шейдерами.

Comment: Спасибо! Правильно ли я понял что GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE типа для быстрой работы, работа с шейдерами будет вестиcь автоматически? И в этом режиме так же можно работать с шейдорами? или надо обязательно переключиться на GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE?

Comment: @ИльяДударь Не знаю, будет ли он использовать какой-то свой шейдер, или будет рисовать напрямую, но в общем-то это неважно. Про core и compat профили: в GL 3 убрали кучу функций, которые были в GL 2 (`glBegin`/`glEnd` и связанные с ними функции, и рисование без шейдеров). Если поставить core-профиль, то убранных функций честно не будет. А в compat-профиле будут доступны все функции. Насколько я понимаю, core - это подмножество compat.

Comment: @ИльяДударь Лучше стремиться использовать core profile. Некоторые полезные инструменты, например RenderDoc, не любят compat profile. Еще compat где-то может не работать (вроде бы macos его не любит).